# Drupal: GD Image Filtering Low Quality / Poor > Performance

Tags: drupal, ubuntu, drupal-6

I'm getting this message in my Drupal installation:

> GD Image Filtering Low Quality / Poor
>   Performance
>
> The installed version of PHP GD does
>   not support image
>   filtering(desaturate, blur, negate,
>   etc). It was probably compiled using
>   the official GD libraries from
>   http://www.libgd.org instead of the GD
>   library bundled with PHP. You should
>   recompile PHP --with-gd using the
>   bundled GD library. See
>   http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.setup.php.
>   An implementation of imagefilter in
>   PHP will be used in the interim.

I'm using the default GD library in php on Ubuntu 9.04

What are the exact commands to update this library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install php from [dotdeb](http://www.dotdeb.org/). The issue is that debian compiles gd without the extensions that php has added to gd.

The other option is to install [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) and tell drupal to use imagemagick instead of gd. For me image magick works much better than gd anyway. I tried to limit users to uploading 1200x1200 max size images and was always running out of memory in php when they upload larger images.

```
apt-get install imagemagick
```

Comment: +1 imagemagick is definetely a good choice. We use it to produce high-res pictures for print. It is more powerful and has better features (at least from a personal opinion)

Comment: ok thanks. I've now installed the imagemagick toolkit. I've selected it as default, and in the Status I can see it is enabled: "The imagemagick toolkit is selected." However I still don't see my images. I've cleaned all Drupal caches and the browser cache as well.

Comment: The problem is that the imagecache folder is empty. The images are not generated.

Answer (score 0):

[dotdeb](http://www.dotdeb.org/) is the [simplest solution](http://drupal.org/node/134331#comment-983886). If you're running LAMP off of Debian/Ubuntu, you do want dotdeb in your sources in general and not just for this specific issue.